# CMS diffusive dynamic

Tags: options, fixed-income, interest-rates, swaps, cms

As I am landing on a project related to CMS option, I am wondering if one can write dynamic for CMS depending on the pricing model.
For example, is it possible to have a diffusive dynamic for the CMS rate if I suppose that my short rate follows a HW1 dynamic. I tried to derive it by applying Ito lemma but it seems tedious that why I am asking here.
I also would like to know what are limitations of the Hull White model ( 1 factor and 2 factors ) from CMS option pricing point of view.
Thanks